# help understanding polar equation of circle

Tags: integration, vector-analysis

In a problem i am working on, equation of the circle is given to be

$x^2+y^2-2ax=0,z=0$

So the polar equation taking become $r=2a\cos\theta$

So for the purpose of surface integral, $r$ varies from $0$ to $2a\cos\theta$ 
and it is given that $\theta$ varies from $0$ to $\pi$ should it not be till $2\pi$ ?? The integral is to be determined above the plane $z=0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the circle

$$0=x^2+y^2-2ax=(x-a)^2+y^2-a^2\implies (x-a)^2+y^2=a^2$$

a circle centered at $\,(a,0)\;$ and with radius $\;a\;$ , so it has part of $\,x-$axis as one of its diameters and the $\,y-$ axis is tangent to it, and thus I'd say that we have

$$-\frac\pi2\le \theta\le\frac\pi2$$

as you can see if you draw a little sketch of the given circle...

Comment: oh !! got it, Thanks

Comment: Any time, @AmanMittal . Besides *accepting* the answer, don't forget to upvote (in all your questions) *all* the answers you found helpful.